# GUI thread not updating correctly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I define a click event for a div "generate board".  When you click it, a random sudoku board is generated.  The problem is I want the div to have a flashing effect while the board is being generated, but it isn't flashing until the generate_random_board() function finishes.  I put a timeout function there so that the GUI thread regains control and updates.  This works for changing the text/board input, but not the fading effect (in the for loop).  Does anyone know why this is, and how to solve it?  Again, I just want the div to flash while the "generate_random_board()" function is running, and stop when it is done.  Thank you!

Here is the relevant code:

```
$('.generate_board').click(function(){ // generate a random board click
                    $(this).text('Generating Board...');
                    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                            $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
                    }
                    $('.board_input').val('');
                    $('.sudoku_message_box').text('This uses an NP-hard algorithm, so it can take a while...');
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                            generate_random_board();
                    }, 30);  
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fades are likely eating each other.  Instead, try chaining them in this fashion:

```
function fadeInOutSlow( obj, x ){
    obj.fadeTo( 'slow', 0.5, function(){
        obj.fadeTo( 'slow', 1.0, function(){
            if ( ( x-1) > 0 ) fadeInOutSlow( obj, x-1 );
        });
    });
}

$('.generate_board').click(function(){ // generate a random board click
                    $(this).text('Generating Board...');
                    fadeInOutSlow( $(this), 3 );
                    $('.board_input').val('');
                    $('.sudoku_message_box').text('This uses an NP-hard algorithm, so it can take a while...');
                    window.setTimeout(function(){
                            generate_random_board();
                    }, 30);  
            });
```

Comment: The third parameter passed to `obj.fadeTo()` is the callback function. This function does not execute until AFTER the transition has completed, which is why this method is successful -- it can't fade out while fading back in (which is likely what was happening with your 3 in a row fade out/in)

Comment: My method works, it's just that it doesn't start flashing until after generate_random_board().  I can take the for loop out completely, and it still does the same thing.  I tried your code, and it does the same waiting thing. :-\

Comment: Do you have the example online somewhere? It's hard to see what might be causing the problem out of context of the rest of your setup.